# How to summarize two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, summarize

This is my first array:

```js
first_arr = [["кстати", 1], ["скажем", 1], ["блин", 1], ["реально", 1], ["вообще", 1], ["допустим", 1], ["фактически", 1], ["получается", 1]]
```

And the second:

```js
second_arr = [['кстати', 1], ['скажем', 2], ['реально', 3], ['вообще', 3], ['ладно', 5]]
```

How can I summarize it to be like:

```js
final_arr = [["кстати", 2], ["скажем", 3], ["блин", 1], ["реально", 4], ["вообще", 4], ["допустим", 1], ["фактически", 1], ["получается", 1], ['ладно', 5]]
```

Comment: `var first_arr = [["кстати", 1], ["скажем", 1], ["блин", 1], ["реально", 1], ["вообще", 1], ["допустим", 1], ["фактически", 1], ["получается", 1]]

var second_arr = [['кстати', 1], ['скажем', 2], ['реально', 3], ['вообще', 3], ['ладно', 5]]

const combined = Object.entries([...first_arr, ...second_arr].reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
    acc[key] = (acc[key] || 0) + value;
    return acc;
}, {}));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate the two arrays and [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) over it, incrementing the count of each key. Then, call [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) on the result:

```js
first_arr = [["кстати", 1], ["скажем", 1], ["блин", 1], ["реально", 1], ["вообще", 1], ["допустим", 1], ["фактически", 1], ["получается", 1]]
second_arr = [['кстати', 1], ['скажем', 2], ['реально', 3], ['вообще', 3], ['ладно', 5]]

const res = Object.entries(first_arr.concat(second_arr).reduce((a, [key, val]) => (a[key] = (a[key] || 0) + val, a), {}))
console.log(res)
```